# Order of evaluation of subexpressions

Tags: c, operator-precedence

If the order of evaluation of sub expressions is not guaranteed, then why is this correct?

```
int a = 1;
a = a + 1;
```

Here the compiler could evaluate first `a` and then `a + 1` so a can be 1 or 2
while this is not:

```
a = a++;
```

Here the compiler could evaluate first `a` and then `a++` son a can be 1 or 2.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behavior. The reason follows::

> The Standard in §5/4 says
>
> Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall
>   have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an
>   expression.

and

> The prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be
>   stored.

It means, that between two sequence points a variable must not be modified more than once and, if an object is written to within a full expression, any and all accesses to it within the same expression must be directly involved in the computation of the value to be written.

Answer (score 0):

Read about sequence points [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) , basically you have 2 assignments between 2 sequence points and that will cause undefined behavior.

`a++` will increment value for `a` and then assign it to `a` and another assignment will be done by `=` operator, while `a + 1` will not change value for `a` and you will have only 1 assignment between 2 sequence points